# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Question') when try to aim to Object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

The Program works when i modify something inside the code for example add a console.log but the second i refresh the page it retrun an error of Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Question') because i was aiming to an object called Question but then when i add a console.log it turns out to be fine again but when i refresh it goes to the same error. What is wrong with the code. This is my code below.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'
//import {themeColor , darkThemeColor} from '../utils/index'
import axios from 'axios';
//import Bottom from '../AddQuestion/index2'
import { Link as LinkRouter , useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function UpdateQuestion() {
    //const title = localStorage.getItem('title');
    //const subject = localStorage.getItem('subject');

    const navi = useNavigate();

    //const questions = [5]
    // const question =
    // {
    //  questionText: '',
    //     qID:'',
    //  answer:'',
    //     choice2:'',
    //     choice3:'',
    //     choice4:'',
    // };
    
    //const [isClick, setIsClick] = useState(false);
    const [finished,setfinished] = useState(false);
    const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);
    const [currentQuestionID, setCurrentQuestionID] = useState(0);

    // const [questionText,setQuestionText] = useState();
    // const [answer,setAnswer] = useState();
    // const [choice2,setChoice2] = useState();
    // const [choice3,setChoice3] = useState();
    // const [choice4,setChoice4] = useState();
    //const[input,setInput] = useState([]);
    //const []
    //const [inputNotEmpty,setInputNotEmpty]=useState(false);
    const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState({});
    const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false);
    const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({});
    const [questions,setQuestions] = useState({});
    


    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const {name, value} = e.target;
        setFormValues({...formValues, [name]: value});
    };
    
    const check = (formValues) =>{
        if(!formValues.questionText || !formValues.answer || !formValues.choice2 || !formValues.choice3 || !formValues.choice4){
            return false
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    const update=()=>{
        if (currentQuestion < 4) {
                //console.log(currentQuestion);
                setCurrentQuestion(currentQuestion+1);
                console.log("updated")
        } else {
                setfinished(true);
                navi("/")
        }   
    }

    const setInputs = () => {
        setCurrentQuestionID(questions[currentQuestion].QuestionID);
        console.log("AAA")
        console.log(questions[currentQuestion].Question);
        setFormValues.answer=questions[currentQuestion].answer;
        setFormValues.choice2=questions[currentQuestion].choice2;
        setFormValues.choice3=questions[currentQuestion].choice3;
        setFormValues.choice4=questions[currentQuestion].choice4;
    }

    //UPDATE SQL
    const handleSubmit=()=>{
        //e.preventDefault();
        //console.log(questions.Question);
        console.log("handlesubmit");
        setFormErrors(check(formValues));
        //setIsSubmit(true);
        const sendData = {
            Question: formValues.questionText,
            answer: formValues.answer,
            choice2:formValues.choice2,
            choice3:formValues.choice3,
            choice4:formValues.choice4,
            // //QuizID:localStorage.getItem("quizID"),
            QuestionID:currentQuestionID,
        };
        console.log(sendData);
        console.log(currentQuestionID);
        axios.post('http://localhost/php/updateQuestion.php',sendData)
        //.then(res=>res.json())
        .then(res=>{
            console.log(res.data);
            if(res.data.data === 'failed'){
                alert('Invalid input');
            }
        } )
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error.response)
        })
        update();
        setInputs();
    }

    //SET ANSWER
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("use effect");
        getData();
        setInputs();
    },[])

    function getData(){
        const sendData = {
            QuizID: localStorage.getItem("quizid")
        }
        console.log(sendData);
        axios.post("http://localhost/php/getLesson.php", sendData)
        .then(res=>{
            console.log(res.data.quiz);
            setQuestions(res.data.quiz);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error.response)
        })
    }

    // function kontol(){
    //     console.log(questions);
    //     console.log(questions[0].Question)
    // }
    return (
        <Container>
            <ContainerOne>
                <QuizTitle>
                    <TitleProperty>Title: {}</TitleProperty>
                </QuizTitle>
                <SubjectTitle>
                    <SubjectProperty>Subject: {localStorage.getItem("subject")}</SubjectProperty>
                </SubjectTitle>
            </ContainerOne>

        {finished ?(
            <>
                <h1>DONE</h1>
            </>    
        ):(
            <>
                {/* set the question id
                
                setCurrentQuestionID(questions.questionID)*/}
                <ContainerTwo>
                    <QuestionTotal>
                        <QuestionTotalProperty>Question {currentQuestion + 1} of 5</QuestionTotalProperty>
                    </QuestionTotal>
                    <Questions>
                        <QuestionsProperty type="text" name="questionText" placeholder="Questions" value={formValues.questionText} onChange={handleChange}/>
                    </Questions>
                </ContainerTwo>

                <ContainerThree>
                    <ContainerAnswers>
                        <AnswerOne>                
                            <Label>Answer</Label>
                            <AnswerProperty type="text" name="answer" placeholder="Answer" value={formValues.answer} onChange={handleChange}/>
                        </AnswerOne>
                        <AnswerTwo>               
                            <Label>choice 1</Label>
                            <AnswerProperty type="text" name="choice2" placeholder="Choice 2" value={formValues.choice2} onChange={handleChange}/>
                        </AnswerTwo>
                        <AnswerThree>
                            <Label>choice 2</Label>
                            <AnswerProperty type="text" name="choice3" placeholder="Choice 3" value={formValues.choice3} onChange={handleChange} />
                        </AnswerThree>
                        <AnswerFour>
                            <Label>choice 3</Label>
                            <AnswerProperty type="text" name="choice4" placeholder="Choice 4" value={formValues.choice4} onChange={handleChange}/>
                        </AnswerFour>
                    </ContainerAnswers>
                </ContainerThree>
                {check(formValues)&&<NextQuestion onClick={() => handleSubmit()}> Next Question </NextQuestion>}
            </>
    )}
    </Container>
  )
}

export default UpdateQuestion
```

The problem is not in the back end because it returns this

`(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: {QuestionID: '1', Question: '1+1', answer: '2', choice2: '', choice3: 'aa', …}1: {QuestionID: '2', Question: 'A=5, A?', answer: '5', choice2: '', choice3: '32', …}2: {QuestionID: '3', Question: '1324', answer: '1324', choice2: '14', choice3: '143', …}3: {QuestionID: '4', Question: 'fgs', answer: 'fgs', choice2: 'qwer', choice3: 'qwert', …}4: {QuestionID: '5', Question: 'qwerty', answer: 'qwerty', choice2: '1235', choice3: 'sfh', …}length: 5[[Prototype]]: Array(0)`

So the problem should be in the front end when i set it to the useState. can anyone help :(

Comment: For more concrete help clean up your code and isolate the portion that is actually throwing the error. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt. But, on an initial scan of your code, you're initializing `questions` as an object, but then apparently setting it at as an array. Secondly, on the first render the data won't have been fetched yet so `questions` will be an empty object meaning `questions[0]` will be undefined.

Comment: so does this mean i have to wait till its fetched then i can call the questions?

Comment: if so when should i call the question to show it in the front end

Comment: You just need to check if `questions` has been set yet. Is questions supposed to be an array? If so just check `questions.length` before trying to work with it.

Comment: alright ill try, btw do you know how to input the different objects/arrays into the front end?